# Select all rows from start of the year, month, week and day in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to be able to select all the rows from the start of a year, month, week and day on the current day from a MySQL database..

For example, let's suppose that today's date is 12th March 2017.

- The year query would select all posts from the start of 2017
- The month query would select all posts from the start of March 2017
- The week query would select all posts from the start of the weeks that date is on
- The day query would select all posts from the start of 12th March 2017

In  the database I have got a 'date added' column which stores dates in the format of '2017-03-12'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data type of 'date added'?  And what SQL queries have you tried?

Comment: Reads like a homework question

Comment: Yes @ChrisCaviness it seems like more and more questions these days do....

Comment: definitely a homework question - posted the link, but deleted immediately since it showed an answer lol

Comment: @ChrisCaviness This is not a 'homework' question and I have tried many different ways for this to work but haven't been successful

Comment: @dstudeba 'date_added' is a varchar but everything is the normal YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: Please show your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use curdate(). Query can be

```
    select * from tbname where tddate>=curdate() --date query
    select * from tbname where month(tbdate)>=month(curdate()) AND year(tdbdate)>=year(curdate()) --month query
    select * from tbname where year(tbdate)>=year(curdate()) --year query
```